# How do I make a custom highlight in css?

Tags: css, highlight, underline

[image]

^ Something like that - is it using :after ? (wasnt able to do it for multiple lines)

```
.home-about h3:after{
 margin-top:-15px;
 content: " ";
 background:#d7edf4;
 z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: you could use the position property on both h3 and :after

Comment: The `::after` pseudo-element has two colons. One colon is old syntax that shouldn't be used anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a pseudo element. Here's a way absolutely positioned in the h3 with a negative z-index.

```css
h3 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

h3:after {
  content: " ";
  background: #d7edf4;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: .4em;
}
```

```html
<h3>text</h3>
```

Comment: The `::after` pseudo-element has two colons. One colon is old syntax that shouldn't be used anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: @Rob yeah I know, but older versions of IE don't recognize `::after` and only work with `:after`, yet all of the newer browsers support both. Until modern browsers stop supporting `:after` I'd rather cover my bases and use `:after` for browser compliance. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc304078(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Let's say it this way. If you **must** support Microsoft's Internet Explorer version 8 or older, then use `:after`. No other reason. Otherwise, quit supporting Microsoft Internet Explorer 8 and older.

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```

Below is the code in action:

```css
.Pink::selection {background: #ffb7b7; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */}
.Pink::-moz-selection {background: #ffb7b7; /* Gecko Browsers */}

.DarkRed::selection {background: #ff0000; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */}
.DarkRed::-moz-selection {background: #ff0000; /* Gecko Browsers */}
```

```html
<p class="Pink">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tristique quam in ex posuere, eu commodo velit sodales. Vestibulum at volutpat lorem, quis interdum diam. Phasellus metus sem, lobortis eu neque eget, tincidunt hendrerit purus. Sed mollis orci dapibus lectus blandit, eget fringilla sapien ullamcorper. Aenean accumsan justo sit amet sapien finibus tincidunt. Nam vitae purus ligula. Nunc quis neque id enim ultricies euismod at id metus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed suscipit, augue id tempus blandit, orci sem faucibus turpis, ac volutpat sem enim eleifend dui. Maecenas congue augue at lacus viverra rhoncus. </p>

<p class="DarkRed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tristique quam in ex posuere, eu commodo velit sodales. Vestibulum at volutpat lorem, quis interdum diam. Phasellus metus sem, lobortis eu neque eget, tincidunt hendrerit purus. Sed mollis orci dapibus lectus blandit, eget fringilla sapien ullamcorper. Aenean accumsan justo sit amet sapien finibus tincidunt. Nam vitae purus ligula. Nunc quis neque id enim ultricies euismod at id metus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed suscipit, augue id tempus blandit, orci sem faucibus turpis, ac volutpat sem enim eleifend dui. Maecenas congue augue at lacus viverra rhoncus. </p>
```

Let me know how you go.

Cheers